# android getResources() from non-Activity class

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to load my vertices array from assets/model.txt 
I have OpenGLActivity, GLRenderer and Mymodel classes
i added this line to the OpenGLActivity:

```
public static Context context;
```

And this to Mymodel class:

```
Context context = OpenGLActivity.context;
    AssetManager am = context.getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = am.open("model.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
    long numfloats = s.nextLong();
    float[] vertices = new float[(int) numfloats];
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < vertices.length; ctr++) {
        vertices[ctr] = s.nextFloat();
    }
```

But it does'n work (

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found in Android it is very important with Activities (and most other classes) not to have references to them in static variables. I try to avoid them at all costs, they love causing memory leaks. But there is one exception, a reference to the application object, which is of course a `Context`. Holding a reference in a static to this will never leak memory.

So what I do if I really need to have a global context for resources is to extend the Application object and add a static get function for the context.

```
In the manifest do....
<application    android:name="MyApplicationClass" ...your other bits....>
```

And in Java....

```
public class MyApplicationClass extends Application
{
   private Context appContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {//Always called before anything else in the app
     //so in the rest of your code safe to call MyApplicationClass.getContext();
         super.onCreate();
         appContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext()
    {
         return appContext;
    }
}
```