# Android: How do you access a string-array from strings.xml in a custom class?

Tags: android, arrays

I'd like to get my string-array without extending Activity in my custom class. Is there a way to do this?

`String[] foo_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foo_array);` will not work without extending Activity, so I need a work-around.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Pass the context to the constructor of custom class and use the same

```
new CustomClass(ActivityName.this);
```

Then

```
Context mContext;
public CustomClass(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
}
```

use the context

```
String[] foo_array = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foo_array);
```

Also keep in mind

Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself)

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Also check this

[android getResources() from non-Activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463491/android-getresources-from-non-activity-class)

Edit:

Change this

```
public class CustomClass(Context context) 
{
}
```

To

```
public class CustomClass
{
   Context mContext;
   public CustomClass(Context context) // constructor 
   {
    mContext = context;
   }
}
```

Comment: When I change my custom class to `public class CustomClass(Context context) {}` it gives me errors saying `Syntax error on token "(", { expected`.

Comment: @JosephWebber you need to have a constructor not alter the synxtax of class declaration. check the edit

Comment: @JosephWebber check the edit it should work and also check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @ Raghunandan Thanks. I misinterpreted what you said, but I remember how to do it now.

Answer (score 9):

try this,

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
String[] foo_array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foo_array);
```

And, do not use Activity Context as that is tied to the Activity life cycle.

**Update**,

`getApplicationContext()` is from Context class. That means any thing extended Context have this method. This also means you will be able to use this from `service` or from other resources.

But, if you custom class do not extend Activity/context, you have to pass Context as parameter to use `getApplicationContext()`

if you declare your activity like this

```
myMethod(Activity activity) //this is bad
```

Bud if it is like following,

```
myMethod(Context context) //this is ok
```

but from above declaration do not pass `Activity` or `Service` `Context` as they have own life cycle. instead you will use `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: `Context context=getApplicationContext();` then gives the error `The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type CustomClass`.

Comment: why is this `myMethod(Activity activity)` bad? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html. Activity is a known indirect subclass of Context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Answer (score 0):

You need pass the Activity context to the Custom class.

```
private Context context;
public CustomClass(Context context)
{
 this.context=context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use numberpicker and pass String from sring xml then use this

np_Basic_Hight.setMinValue(0);

```
    np_Basic_Hight.setMaxValue(71);
    np_Basic_Hight.setDisplayedValues(getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hieght));
```