# How can I use Spinner with ID or Key with String.XML

Tags: java, android, json, spinner, sha1

How I USE my String.XML using spinner. 
where my spinner show Array PDAM
and my parse show ID_PDAM

**String.XML**

*string for dropdown PDAM

```
<array name="PDAM">
    <item>PILIH PDAM</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirtanadi</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirta Jati (Cirebon)</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirta Umbu Kab.Nias</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirta Patriot</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirta Benteng</item>
    </array>
<array name="ID_PDAM">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>801204</item>
    <item>803216</item>
    <item>801208</item>
    <item>803220</item>
    <item>803605</item>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it will help you surely:

```
<string-array name="PDAM">
    <item>PILIH PDAM</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirtanadi</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirta Jati (Cirebon)</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirta Umbu Kab.Nias</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirta Patriot</item>
    <item>PDAM Tirta Benteng</item>
    </string-array>
<string-array name="ID_PDAM">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>801204</item>
    <item>803216</item>
    <item>801208</item>
    <item>803220</item>
    <item>803605</item>
</string-array>
```

In your layout need `ID_PDAM` then change your array name in xml:

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/PDAM"
    />
```

after that you will need to get it from the string.xml by using:

```
String[] array name = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_name);
```

Use Adapter for spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: okay i will try it

Comment: on my apps it's still from PDAM not from ID_PDAM

i mean on Spinner it's PDAM show and on backend App ID_PDAM

now on Spinner PDAM and on Backend Still PDAM'

Comment: share your java code also

Comment: Here

https://pastebin.com/raw/b2kvmYnA

Comment: can you provide me xml file of this activity?

Comment: here the XML for Activity

https://pastebin.com/raw/sqchaiuJ

Comment: i have make some changes copy and paste in your activity java class and string file [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KiLwEb1F_k-viiMlcUH4XDXHeOuWWqwn)
may be it will work

Comment: can't change @abhinav

Comment: yes I have changed that time spinner was showing ID_PDAM in the UI. I have done by own.

Comment: thx abhinav that solved with using

final String pdam = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final int spinner_pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        String[] idpdam = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ID_PDAM);
        final int pdam1 = Integer.valueOf(idpdam[spinner_pos]);

and just get from pdam1

Answer (score 0):

First of all in string.xml u need a string array:

```
<string-array
    name="string_array_name">
    <item>text_string</item>
</string-array>
```

after that you will need to get it from the string.xml by using:

```
String[] foo_array = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_name);
```

Then you need to add it normally:

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Ref:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

[Android: How do you access a string-array from strings.xml in a custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408194/android-how-do-you-access-a-string-array-from-strings-xml-in-a-custom-class)

[Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)